# Simple TCP Proxy for Amazon Linux 2

Tags: yum, proxy, tcp, amazon-linux

I'm looking for a simple TCP proxy that I can install and run on Amazon Linux 2. I've been using [simpleproxy](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/simpleproxy.1.html) on Ubuntu and it does exactly what I need, but I can't seem to find an equivalent for Amazon Linux (or Red Hat, or CentOS, or anything else that uses `yum`).

Any recommendations on the cleanest, simplest way to have a proxy where a given port (any TCP port, not limited to HTTP/HTTPS) on the local machine is proxied to a given port on a remote machine?

Comment: Are you using a VM on AWS (like EC2) ? That's looks like a XY-problem, AWS should provide you with a way to proxify any port (incomming or outgoing) on your VM (altough, understanding AWS might not be easy)

Comment: I'm using a Docker container running on AWS ECS. The objective is to build a Dockerized bastion host, which is a common use for EC2 (but we're trying to do something more immutable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use `socat`. I had actually used it on a previous project but just forgot about it.